# Java Regular Expression; need to map \' to ''

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to map the `\'` to `''`. That is, a string consisting of a backslash followed immediately by a single quote should be mapped to two single quotes.

I've tried using

```
string = string.replace("\'", "''")
```

but this also maps a single quote to two single quotes (i.e., `"'"` to `"''"`), which is incorrect for what I need. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the backslash? As in `"\\'"`?

Comment: your text has `\'` visible like that? two characters? You'd have to search for `"\\'"`, as `\'` in a java `"`-quoted string isn't anything special.

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment to Kasramvd, I had tried escaping the backslash, but that caused a different unit test to fail. The problem was with that unit test. Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Backslash here is a escape character and it just will match `'` if you want to match `\'` you need `\\'`:

```
string = string.replace("\\'", "''")
```

Comment: Yes, thank you; this is correct. I had tried this, but one of my other unit tests was failing. It turns out the unit test was flawed.

Answer (score 1):

The "\" needs to be escaped itself because it is a special character. `"\\'", "''"`